# Rejection sampling to simulate gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, simulation

I am reading "Explorations in Monte Carlo Methods" by Shonkwiler and Mendivil. I don't understand the following explanation for choosing a proposal distribution $g$ to simulate the distribution $Gamma(\alpha)$ for $ 0 < \alpha < 1$. The target density function is

$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x}, x \ge 0$.

$g$'s form is $px^{\alpha-1}\unicode{x1D7D9}_{[0,1]} + (1-p)e^{1-x}\unicode{x1D7D9}_{(1,\infty)}$. It makes sense to split $g$ into a $[0,1]$ part and a $(1,\infty)$ part, because random variables with density functions of the form $kx^{k-1}\unicode{x1D7D9}_{[0,1]}$ and $e^{1-x}\unicode{x1D7D9}_{(1,\infty)}$ are simple to simulate.

Now the book states that $p$ should be chosen so that

(*) $lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} g(x) = e \cdot{} lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+} g(x)$;

this is the part I don't understand. The explanation given is that at $x=1$ the value of $x^{\alpha - 1}$ is $e$ times as big as that of $e^{-x}$. I don't understand, what does this fact have to do with $g$ or $p$?

I understand that in the end we will need to find $M$ such that $\forall x, Mg(x) \ge f(x)$, so $p$ has to satisfy

$Mpx^{\alpha-1} \ge \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x}$ in $[0,1]$ and
$M(1-p)e^{1-x} \ge \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x}$ in $(1,\infty)$, but what does this have to do with (*)?

Comment: At $x=1$ the value of $x^{\alpha - 1}$ is $1$ while  that of $e^{-x}$ is $e^{-1}$, and $1=e\times e^{-1}$

Comment: @Henry How is that relevant to $g(x)$? Sorry for asking something that might seem obvious to you.